# Bulk load data conversion error from csv file to SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert, mismatch

I have this problem inserting my data from csv file to my SQL database.
I just don't get it why there is a error when i already replace some unwanted characters. it should be able to insert but i got this error.

"Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 13 (creditLimit)."

this is my create table:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers(
    customerNumber integer NOT NULL,
    customerName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    customerLastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    customerFirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Phone varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    addressLine1 varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    addressLine2 varchar(50) NULL,
    city varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [state] varchar(50) NULL,
    postalCode varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    country varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    salesRepEmployeeNumber integer NOT NULL,
    creditLimit double precision NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY(customerNumber) );
```

this is the first few lines of my csv file:

> first line- 103,Atelier graphique,Schmitt,Carine ,40.32.2555,54  rue
>   Royale,NULL,Nantes,NULL,44000,France,1370,21000
>
> second line- 112,Signal Gift Stores,King,Sue,7025551838,8489 Strong
>   St.,NULL,Las Vegas,NV,83030,USA,1166,71800

im not sure why is there error can you please help me?

Comment: are you using mysql or sql-server? please don't tag both if the question only belongs to one of them.

Comment: What bulk load tool are you using - BCP? What command line and definition file are you using?

Comment: Could you show your bulk insert statement?

Comment: BULK INSERT Customers
FROM 'C:\Users\Student\Desktop\BIca1folder\CustomersBI.csv'
WITH (fieldterminator=',', rowterminator='/n')

@HoneyBadger

Comment: im using my SQL @CeOnSql

Comment: Does it work if you remove the dots in the numbers? (ie: 40.32.2555 --> 40322555). (Wouldn't expect it, but it may matter)

Comment: Also, why do you use a float (which is double precision) for credit limit? Wouldnt a decimal be better? A float is an approximate, I wouldn't think you'd want that for credit limit.

Comment: no it  doesn't work. i tried changing the separators and even try and errors on the type(i tried 'money NOT NULL') i seems to be always that row 1, column 13 (creditLimit). @HoneyBadger

Comment: Are there any hidden characters? Did you create the csv yourself? You could check in a hex editor if there are for example line-endings somewhere which cause trouble.

Comment: the csv file i took it from here(is my school project):https://www.dropbox.com/s/akdv45z23oy7npa/Customers.csv?dl=0 

i tried decimal but still cannot D: @HoneyBadger

Comment: There is an inconsistency in your datafile: what sort of decimal seperator are you using, dot or comma? There is `40.32.2555`, which suggest you use comma's, yet the last field which causes the problems has a dot: `21000.00`. If you change this last dot to a comma it should work.

Comment: On second thought, if you change to a comma it won't work, since you use comma's as field seperator. You'll have to change the field seperator to something else as well...

Comment: there isn't 21000.00 is there? its 21000. if i put a comma it will break into another column right? because my fiieldterminator is "," @HoneyBadger.

Comment: In the datafile you send there is a 21000.00, see my previous comment. Since you need to heavily edit the file (change decimal . to , or remove all other dots, and change field seperator as well) you may need to write some tooling to pre-process the file.

Comment: Please check [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/968215). This may solve your issue this is regarding to some SQL server related issue.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd, the link you posted is for date differences, this is not the issue here

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because your rowterminator is wrong ... you should use \n not /n ...